# Bing webmaster tools says bad SEO for embedded SVG containing <title> tags

Tags: html, svg, seo, google-search-console

I am working on a site where I have used SVG directly embedded in the HTML5 page. I use the `<title>` tags within the SVG to get the mouse hover tooltip effect to provide some information about the image.

It all works fine but when I check my site with Bing webmaster tools, it is telling me that the pages for which I have done this have SEO problems due to multiple `<title>` tags within the pages.

Do I actually need to be worried about this? If so are there any alternatives that I can use to get the same effect as that of the `<title>` tag.

Google webmaster tools do not complain about the issue, just Bing so I am really unsure as to whether this is a bad thing or not from SEO perspectives.

Comment: I suppose that depends on how much you're concerned about Bing page rankings...  Seriously, I think the accessibility and SEO *benefits* of using SVG title tags as they are intended should outweigh any loss from a search engine that didn't know the difference between an HTML title tag in the head and an SVG title tag in an inline graphic.  And, it's possible that the Bing search engine algorithm understands SVG title, with only the webmaster tools not catching the nuance.  An alternative for accessibility and SEO is the `<desc>` tag, but visual browsers won't use that for auto-tooltips.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your use of the  tag is correct according to the w3 docs. Make sure that it is the first element within your SVG, and it should be functional in browsers that render it as a tooltip.

As for Bing Webmaster tools, I think this is an oversight on their part. I recommend trying the same type of test using Google Webmaster Tools Fetch and Render Feature to see what Googlebot makes of it. Also running a scan from https://validator.w3.org/ should help ensure your markup is valid.

If you want to ensure tool tip functionality across browsers and avoid any possible SEO issues I recommend using a javascript implementation such as [Foundation's](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/tooltips.html)  or [Bootstrap's](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips).

**Sources:**

- http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html#DescriptionAndTitleElements
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/title